# How to make my web page load in the local language of client

Tags: html, client, locale

I want my web page to load in the local language of a client when the client requests my server for the HTML page. How do I do it?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_google_translate.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement localization in your web application. Here is a article which might help you out.

https://phraseapp.com/blog/posts/step-step-guide-javascript-localization/

When, client asks your web server for web page then in that request your client should send which language they want. You can get this from browser it self i.e. which language client is using.

For Example this is how your response to your client will be:

`<a class="lang-switch" href="#" data-locale="en">English</a>
 <a class="lang-switch" href="#" data-locale="ru">Русский</a>`